# Unhandled rejection OrientDB.RequestError: User or password not valid for username: admin, database: 'demodb'

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

Hy guys,
I'm facing some trouble in connecting to an orientdb database.

Here is my app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const OrientJs = require('orientjs');


var server = OrientJs({
    host: "localhost",
    password: "root",
    username: "root",
    useToken: true
});

var db = server.use({
    name: 'demodb',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'root',
    useToken: true
});

server.list()
    .then(function (dbs) {
        console.log( dbs.length + ': database/s on the server.');
    });


db.select().from('ArchaeologicalSites').all()
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
});
```

The debugger shows this message even if I try to change the password or the username in the server.use() function.

the message from the debugger:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Running at Port 3000
Unhandled rejection OrientDB.RequestError: User or password not valid for username: admin, database: 'demodb'
        DB name="demodb"
    at child.Operation.parseError (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:905:13)
    at child.Operation.consume (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:496:35)
    at Connection.process (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:459:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:331:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:134:14)

1: database/s on the server.
```

So...it correctly connects with server.use(), in fact server.list() works fine.
But when itcomes to the query it shows that maybe the var "db" has something wrong...

When i change the app.js to this:

```
var db = server.use({
    name: 'demodb',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    useToken: true
});
```

the error shown is this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Running at Port 3000
1: database/s on the server.
Unhandled rejection OrientDB.RequestError: Invalid authentication info for access to the database com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.auth.OTokenAuthInfo@1798dbcf
        DB name="demodb"
    at child.Operation.parseError (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:905:13)
    at child.Operation.consume (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:496:35)
    at Connection.process (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:459:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (C:\Users\\source\repos\ExpressApp3\ExpressApp3\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:331:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:134:14)
```

Ceers

Comment: It is telling you the problem quite clearly: `User or password not valid for username: admin`

Comment: Okay, but what if i setted the password for that db as "root" and then i just typed the password i previously setted in the app.js file and it started telling me that the password is incorrect? Seems like I built a lock, then i built the key for that lock and then when i try opening the lock I built it says me that the key doesen't match the lock. It's stressfull...

Comment: Try removing `useToken: true`

Comment: No, you have to use it for the auth. Sooo, i guess i'll be back to vb and access...add the fact that the site of orientdb is under maintenance so i have totally no idea where to find the answer